# Mixing formValidation plugin with another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use [formValidation](http://formvalidation.io) plugin for validating my forms, and I am trying to build a wizard using jQuery. This is my first form:

```
<div id="dynamicContent">
<form id="myForm1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Proceed to step 2 </button>
</form>
</div>
```

(I am trying to control the content of **dynamicContent** div)

This is the JS snippet for the first step:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm1').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify user first name.'
                    }
                }
            },
            surname: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify user last name.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target),
            fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.ajax({
            url: 'step2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $('#dynamicContent').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code is working as expected. Now this is the second step files:

PHP (html file):

```
<?php 
echo "Welcome, ".$_POST["name"]." ".$_POST["surname"];
?>
<form id="myForm2" method="post" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="province" class="form-control" placeholder="Province">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="postalcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Proceed to step 3 </button>
</form>
```

And this is js file for the second step:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm2').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            address: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify address.'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify city.'
                    }
                }
            },
            province: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify province.'
                    }
                }
            },
            postalcode: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify postal code.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target),
            fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.ajax({
            url: 'step3.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $('#dynamicContent').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But when I try to click on **Proceed to step 3** button, nothing will happen. Not even an error!

I tried to change the behavior of the button, as well as the JS. If I change the button from *submit* to normal button an remove form validation part, the Ajax will work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendForm();" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Send it this way">
function sendForm()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'step3.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#dynamicContent').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I do not care if I change the button from submit to normal input type, but form validation matters. How can I make it working?

Comment: form myForm2 is created after the js has been loaded, so you cannot use it directly like you have used it.

Comment: @AparajitPUtpat: But why the second JS is working? If I remove form validation part, I can access the form elements and send it using ajax. In fact, the only problem here is not being able to use form validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you aren't running the JavaScript for your second page. Ajax doesn't fire a second ready event when it completes, so you need to have a way to register your plugin without relying on `$(doucment).ready`. Try using:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$('#myForm2').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
...
```

Just be careful that this isn't in a .js file that gets loaded across your site as this will get called *every* time an ajax call completes. A better way might be to put your initialization into a function (a non-anonymous one) and call it from within the `success:` callback of the plugin, thus chaining the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. regarding $(document).ready, you are right, and I think I should put the form validation part inside sendForm() function. Can you help me to do it? How can I enquire form validation inside sendForm() function?

Comment: Where you have an anonymous function that you want to call, just remove the code and declare it as a function elsewhere, then pass it in. In your case make a `setupForm()` function or something that initializes your second form and call it from your ajax success callback